# Invoke specific lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have multiple users and lambda functions in my AWS account, as an example user1, user2, user3, user4 and have the same name for lambda function as well.

I have created the following policy to invoke the Lambda function, but I am getting a following error:
Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111111:function:${aws.username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/lambda_role",
                "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:111111111111:function:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can create the function without any issue but when I try to invoke the Lambda function, I am getting an error message. However, the policy is attached to the user account.

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Invoke operation: User: arn:aws:iam:: 111111111111:user/user1 is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2: 111111111111:function:user1 because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action
```

Comment: Have you set up the policy with CF? Or are you trying to use pseudo params within the policy?

Comment: I haven't use the CF for the setup and the policy is same as mentioned above.

Comment: My first thought was that ${aws.username} was a pseudo param for CF but I understand you can use that syntax in policys as well. But are you sure you can use it in the resource section of the policy? The example I find this is used in the condition section.

Comment: Looking more into this, this key you try to use is called condition keys. Read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html

Comment: I am using this {aws.username} in other policies and they are working fine. However, I am facing problem with the Lambda function only.

Comment: Does each IAM user actually have the IAM policy shown?

Comment: Yes!!! That is how it supposed to be and all the users have this policy attached

Comment: Have you tried to hardcode the user name in the function name to see if that works?

Comment: yes I tried everything but it is not working!!I have even tried passing the full ARN of the function.

Comment: @user2670674 looks like am not alone with this issues.. I have tried all possible option but end up in same error. Looks like AWS has to look at the problem